# ionic start fails for node-sass

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, node-gyp, node-sass

When I run

```
sudo ionic start newapp blank
```

I get errors for node-sass:

```
Unable to save binary /home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48 : { Error: 
        EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
             at Error (native)
             at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:924:18)
             at sync (/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
             at Function.sync (/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
             at checkAndDownloadBinary (/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
             at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
             at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
             at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
             at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
             at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
           errno: -13,
           code: 'EACCES',
           syscall: 'mkdir',
           path: '/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }
```

then

```
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
        '/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
        "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/code/newapp/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I've been messing around with permissions, manually creating directories and globally installing node-sass. But I can't get ionic start to succeed.

ionic: v3.18.0, node: v6.11.5, npm: v5.5.1, node-sass: v4.5.3

Comment: Why do you use `sudo`? Can't you just start your new app in a folder where you don't need superuser privileges?

Comment: Yes. Yes I should do that. I've been staring at this for far too long :)

Comment: Does it correct your problem? I had a similar issue when installing packages as root with npm. I had to add the `--unsafe-perm` flag to the npm commands...

Comment: It does, thank you. I've had issues where certain packages require root and subsequent scripts were run with the wrong permissions. In this instance however it was a case of not seeing the wood for the trees.